# Using glob function to include different image parameters

Tags: php

```
$pictures = glob(path('public') . 'uploads/galleries/' . $dir_name . '/' . '*.jpg');
```

Right now it only retrieves `.jpg` files from a directory. However, I want it to be retrieving .JPG, .png, .PNG or others too.

I wonder if `*.jpg` can be used like; `*.jpg|*.JPG|*.png|*.PNG` or if I can attach a regex which basically does the same thing.

If `glob()` doesn't support such use, what would you suggest for this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use curly braces:

```
'*.{jpg,JPG,png,PNG}'
```